# iOS 9 HTTPS App Transport Security connection

Tags: ios, iphone, https, app-transport-security

I have an app which I want to update for iOS9 now. The problem is that I'm getting error: `CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed` even though I have HTTPS connection. That's the error if the app is not connecting to HTTPS and that is fine and that is ok. My developer server is HTTPS as is production. I don't want to exclude and break security. I do not want to bypass that. I know I can add Per-domain exceptions to my Info.plist file. I've checked my server and it supports TLS 1.2. What's the problem?

Comment: There is apple's documentation, you need to configure Transport Security according to your server settings 
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/